# Error when using ft_one_hot_encoder() in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with a categorical variable that I want to encode using one-hot encoding in `sparklyr`. Below is the table head, and the code I'm using:

[image]

`tbl_name %>%
  ft_one_hot_encoder(input_col="category",output_col="category_x")`

However, I'm getting the following error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Input column must be of type numeric but got string`. I may be missing something here, but how can the input column of the one-hot encoder be numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read on Luraschi's book that `ft_string_indexer()` need to be used before applying `ft_one_hot_encoder()` in `sparklyr`.